# Website down Call to a member function get_item_quantity() on null

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website which is down. The error I am getting at Line A

```
    $feed_details = get_feed_data();
    // Localize the current index number
    wp_localize_script(
        'headlines-infinite',
        'HELLO_Headlines',
        [
            'endpoint' => home_url( '/api/headline' ),
            'currentIndex' => get_query_var( 'page' ),
            'itemCount' => $feed_details->get_item_quantity() + 1,            // Line A
        ]
    );
});
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make at Line A so that I can make the website up.

Comment: check if field details is null

Comment: which field details ?

Comment: sorry i mean feed_details

Comment: The error is clear, the value of `$field_details` is `null`. So the problem is in `get_feed_data()`.

Comment: What is `});` at the end matching?